# there is an OR error in java

Tags: java, if-statement

```
  public void hit(){
if ((( clx + 31 + rectleftup>=500) && ( clx + 31 + rectleftup <=820))) ||(((cly-300>= 500) && (cly-300<=789))) {
 ex = 9999;
return;
}
```

error: illegal start of expression.
Its pointing to the or (||) and i dont know how to fix it.
It should add all the numbers up and check if its with in the numbers given.
there is also a insert ; error at the end of the if statement.

.... ..... ... . .. ... ... . .. ..... . .. . . . .... . . . . .. . ..  . . . .. . . .. .. . .. ... . . .. .... . ... .. . . .. .. . . . . ..

Comment: proper code indentation and not writing everything in one line usually helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second condition is outside the if statement

Comment: ... because you have one too many close-parens before it. (Count it out, and remember that the if's expression must be surrounded in parens.)

Comment: praise the lord, thank you

Comment: Split lines at the && and || symbols and use indentation to help you track parens.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((( clx + 31 + rectleftup>=500) && ( clx + 31 + rectleftup <=820))) || ...
// 123                           2    3                            210
// \_________________________________________________________________/
//                             Bracket balance
```

You have "closed off" the `if` statement condition fully at that final closing bracket above, you are not permitted to keep going.

I suspect it will all work fine if you simply wrap `()` around the whole thing, or remove the closing bracket *before* the `||` and the opening bracket _after`the`||`.

---

You *may* find it's also more readable if you do something like:

```
int p1 = clx + 31 + recleftup; // though use better var name than p1.
int p2 = cly - 300;            // ditto.
if (((p1 >= 500) && (p1 <= 820)) || ((p2 >= 500) && (p2 <= 789))) {
```